# CSS How can i autoscale the text to fit in the container

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My problem right now is when i change the window size there is a scrollbar at the bottom, the picture (which is the container) will fits the screen, but there is a lot of extra white space when I scroll right. so when i change the screen size, the text on the container will move. I changed to use media only screen to change the font size when the size of the screen changes, but this isn't about font size only, the text will move

```
.container {
    background-image: url(../images);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    /*compatible for webkit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    /*compatible for firefox mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /*compatible for opera*/
    background-size: cover;
    /*compatible for generic browsers*/
    margin-top:-5px;
    //max-width:400%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 39%;
    height: 20%;
    left: 420px;
    top: 4020px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:34px;
    font-weight:530;
}
```

I also tried to use position relative instead of absolutely. when i do that, the container image will suddenly gets huge. It's not even fit the screen, it's just gets huge.

Answer (score -1):

```
position: absolute;
```

just wont work until above container has

```
position: relative;
```

Put relative position to your container first.

Comment: I did. I add position relative to my container, what else i should do